# Azure-Application not found listed while assigning the role

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-storage-account

I have created an application and am trying to give the required storage account permission through IAM within a storage account.

I followed below step

1. Create/Register an application
2. Create a secret id within the active directory
3. In the storage account, add a role assignment to the above application
   But I don't see the created application listed under the owner list while I am trying to add a role assignment to the same application.

And I also observed that whenever I navigate to the active directory, it launches with the 'Create Tenant' window every time. I had never seen such a strange case even before.

I am using a default subscription.

Please let me know what issue exactly blocks application to be listed under the owner list?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I created an Azure AD Application:

[image]

I am able to add **role assignment** for the above created application:

*Go to Storage Accounts -> Select your account -> Access Control (IAM) -> Add role assignment -> Select owner ->  Select members -> Your app*

[image]

> Please let me know what issue exactly blocks application to be listed under the owner list?

The issue usually occurs if the Enterprise application/Service Principal is not created for the application like below:

[image]

Now, when I tried to add role assignment, **application is not found in the list**:

[image]

Make sure to create the Service Principal by clicking on **`Create Service Principal`**:

[image]

If you are getting ***'Create Tenant' window every time*** maybe the Microsoft Entra ID tenant is not configured properly or the tenant is not created.

**Make sure to create the Microsoft Entra ID like below:**

[image]

Make sure to have Tenant Creator role to create tenant.

**If still the issue persists**, try assigning role for other application and check.

**Reference:**

[Access & create new tenant - Microsoft Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/create-new-tenant#create-a-new-tenant-for-your-organization)